# PowerShell class constructor - Get-Content returns string not array

Tags: powershell, class, constructor

I have a text file that has a list of test devices as follows.

```
D1
D2
D3
```

I have a class constructor that amongst other things, gets content from the text file and assigns it to a property.

If within the constructor I run `$this.TestList = Get-Content ".\testlist.txt"` I get a string of D1 D2 D3

If within the constructor I run `$TestList = Get-Content ".\testlist.txt"` I get an array.

If I run `$TestList = Get-Content ".\testlist.txt"` followed by `$this.TestList = $TestList` I get a string.

I'm new to classes in PowerShell so it could be a simple code error but I can't work out why this is happening.  Can anyone shed any light on this please?

Edit:

This is a very stripped down version of the code.

```
class CMBuildInfo {
    [string]$TestMachine

    CMBuildInfo () {
        $this.Testmachine = Get-Content "C:\test\ProTestmachines.txt"
    }
}

[CMBuildInfo]$NewApplication = New-Object -TypeName CMBuildInfo -ArgumentList($LatestUpdateInfo)

$NewApplication.TestMachine
```

I've identified the issue and it is the casting of TestMachine in the class.  Originally it was a simple string.  When I decided to switch to an array I put the extra square brackets on the property declaration below TestMachine.

What is interesting is the unintended outcome.  Cast Get-Content to a string and it appears to concatenate each row together with a space deliminator.

Correct code would be:

```
class CMBuildInfo {
    [string[]]$TestMachine

    CMBuildInfo () {
        $this.Testmachine = Get-Content "C:\test\ProTestmachines.txt"
    }
}

[CMBuildInfo]$NewApplication = New-Object -TypeName CMBuildInfo -ArgumentList($LatestUpdateInfo)

$NewApplication.TestMachine
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: There are many solid articles and Youtube videos on PowerShell v5 and beyond classes.   [As well as many Q&A right here on SO on the PS classes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+custom+classes). [What did you search for](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+v5+classes%27&t=h_&ia=web)?  Youtube [videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27powershell+v5+classes%27) regarding PowerShell Classes

Comment: You need to show a simplified version of your class, as well as what you show here. Yet, what you are doing is not valid. See the links pointed to. All in all, this is not a `Get-Content ` cmdlet issue, specifically. It is how you are using it. IN general, classes notwithstanding, PowerShell will always try and be helpful based on what you are passing. Meaning it will recast from one type to the other, based on input or cast assignment, if you don't explicitly cast one way or the other

Comment: Thanks to all that responded.  In response to all the prompts on how to post, I thought it was a simple query which if I'd posted the MRE it would have been; I know better if I post again.
I'd spent hours looking for the answer online and as you can see from the identified fault I was not likely to find that solution online anyway.  Just a dumb error that I couldn't see as my mind was clouded by the fact that classes in PS are new to me.
@postanote - Your considerate efforts are much appreciated.

Comment: No worries, but actually, this class conversion is a regular one all over the web. For example, [in a search, here is one of the better ones](https://xainey.github.io/2016/powershell-classes-and-concepts). However, when looking for answers, you can not rely on finding all you need for your use case. Why, because yours can be specific/creative.  So, you need to break it up into steps/pieces. This means breaking your search string into pieces, using global and exact or concatenated matchs to find. A good book to help search criteria manipulation - Google Hacking, hit Amazon for it.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comments, as extrapolated from the Docs and help files.

1. Understand that the `$this` is only used in the current instance of a class.
2. `$this` is only valid in the context of a method body.
3. Outside the class body, `$this` means nothing, it would return null by design. There is no dot reference, and you can't assign anything to it.
4. `this` is the reference in the class for the value you want to use in an instance of the class, that will be held by the variable content being passed.
5. These, `$this.TestList = Get-Content ".\testlist.txt"`, and
   `$TestList = Get-Content ".\testlist.txt" followed by $this.TestList = $TestList` are not valid for a constructor; since as noted per point #3.

PowerShell will cast on the fly, unless you tell it otherwise, as noted in my comment. Yet, this is really meant for a 1:1 thing, not the content of a file.

A simple class, constructor, and use case is like this:

```
class New_Car {
    # descriptors/properties/state
    [string]$Color
    [string]$Name
    [string]$Manufacturer
    [string]$Model
    [int]$Length
    [int]$Width
    [int]$Height
    [int]$Mileage

    # Methods, to perform on the object
    [void]Drive($Milage)
    {
        <# 
        Reference for a current instance of the object
        and is only valid in this method body
        #>
        $this.Mileage += $Mileage
    }
}


([New_Car]).GetType() | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
IsPublic IsSerial Name        BaseType                  
-------- -------- ----        --------                  
False    True     RuntimeType System.Reflection.TypeInfo
#>


# Instantiate the constructor
($MyNewCar = [New_Car]::new())
# Results
<#
Color        : 
Name         : 
Manufacturer : 
Model        : 
Length       : 0
Width        : 0
Height       : 0
Mileage      : 0
#>

($MyNewCar).GetType() | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
IsPublic IsSerial Name    BaseType     
-------- -------- ----    --------     
True     False    New_Car System.Object
#>

$MyNewCar | Get-Member
# Results
<#
   TypeName: New_Car

Name         MemberType   Definition                      
----         ----------   ----------                      
Drive        Method       void Drive(System.Object Milage)
Equals       Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)  
GetHashCode  Method       int GetHashCode()               
GetType      Method       type GetType()                  
ToString     Method       string ToString()               
Color        Property     string Color {get;set;}         
Height       Property     int Height {get;set;}           
Length       Property     int Length {get;set;}           
Manufacturer Property     string Manufacturer {get;set;}  
Mileage      Property     int Mileage {get;set;}          
Model        Property     string Model {get;set;}         
Name         Property     string Name {get;set;}          
Width        Property     int Width {get;set;}
#>

$MyNewCar.Drive(9)
$MyNewCar
# Results
<#
Color        : 
Name         : 
Manufacturer : 
Model        : 
Length       : 0
Width        : 0
Height       : 0
Mileage      : 9
#>

$MyNewCar.Manufacturer = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\CarMakers.txt'
$MyNewCar
# Results
<#
Color        : 
Name         : 
Manufacturer : BMW GM Ford
Model        : 
Length       : 0
Width        : 0
Height       : 0
Mileage      : 9
#>

$CarFolks = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\CarMakers.txt'
$MyNewCar.Manufacturer = $CarFolks
$MyNewCar
# Results
<#
Color        : 
Name         : 
Manufacturer : BMW GM Ford
Model        : 
Length       : 0
Width        : 0
Height       : 0
Mileage      : 9
#>
```

Doing this, in the constructor...

```
$this.
```

...yields no IntelliSense, no results for anything, and as a reserved word/feature, cannot/should not be used for other purposes.

Lastly, if you are trying to load up more than one thing in a class, then, you are looking at constructor overloading. So, this...

```
Class Car
{
    [String]$vin
    static [int]$numberOfWheels = 4
    [int]$numberOfDoors
    [datetime]$year
    [String]$model

    Car ([string]$vin)
    {$this.vin = $vin        }
    Car ([string]$vin, [string]$model)
    {
        $this.vin   = $vin
        $this.model = $model
    }
    Car ([string]$vin, [string]$model, [datetime]$year)
    {
        $this.vin   = $vin
        $this.model = $model
        $this.year  = $year
    }
    Car ([string]$vin, [string]$model, [datetime]$year, [int]$numberOfDoors)
    {
        $this.vin  = $vin
        $this.model = $model
        $this.year  = $year
        $this.numberOfDoors = $numberOfDoors
    }
}
[car]::new
# Results
<#
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
Car new(string vin)
Car new(string vin, string model)
Car new(string vin, string model, datetime year)
Car new(string vin, string model, datetime year, int numberOfDoors)
#>

[car]::new(1234, 'chevy', '1/2/2015', 3)
# Results
<#
vin  numberOfDoors year               model
---  ------------- ----               -----
1234             3 02-Jan-15 00:00:00 chevy
#>
```

See details here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-5-classes-constructor-overloading